new environment counter in beamer overlay
I've looked for an answer to a similar question, but couldn't find one.
I've created a new environment 'test' as follows:
\newcounter{test}
\newenvironment{test}[1][]{\refstepcounter{test}\par\medskip
\noindent\textbf{Test~\thetest #1:}}{\medskip}

The problem is that in a frame that have some kind of overlay (\pause, \onslide or \uncover) 'Test' is counted more than once, one count for each overlay, but I want the Test to be counted only once.
MWE:
\documentclass[english,11pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcounter{test}
\newenvironment{test}[1][]{\refstepcounter{test}\par\medskip
\noindent\textbf{Test~\thetest #1:}}{\medskip}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{test}
whatever
\end{test}
\pause\\
this was a test
\end{frame}
\end{document}


"I've looked for an answer to a similar question, but couldn't find one." That's exactly why your question should be marked as duplicate: it will be a signpost for future users with the same problem to help them find the existing answers! Voting to leave closed.

You can use \resetcounteronoverlays{...} to add your custom counter to the list of counters which get reset on every overlay:
\documentclass[english,11pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcounter{test}
\newenvironment{test}[1][]{\refstepcounter{test}\par\medskip
\noindent\textbf{Test~\thetest #1:}}{\medskip}


\resetcounteronoverlays{test}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\begin{test}
whatever
\end{test}
\pause\\
this was a test
\end{frame}
\end{document}


it worked perfectly!
